# I can't delete item in recyclerview using room database and coroutines

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room

I am new with android jetpack components but as a learner, I want to make a note app, in this app, I am using room database and coroutines. and it's successfully insert, update but I can't delete.
here is my code, it might be long
ShowFragment

```
class ShowFragment : BaseFragment(),onItemClickListener {
private var customerNote:Customer? = null
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show, container, false)
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)

    launch {
        context?.let {
            val c = CustomerDatabase(it).getNoteDao().getAllNote()
            recyclerView.adapter = ShowAdapter(c as ArrayList<Customer>,this@ShowFragment)
            it.toast("Show!")

        }
    }

    add_button.setOnClickListener {
        val action = ShowFragmentDirections.actionAddNote()
        Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(action)
    }
}

override fun onClick(item: Customer, position: Int) {
    launch {
                context?.let {
                    CustomerDatabase(it).getNoteDao().noteDelete(customerNote!!)
                    it.toast("Deleted!")
                }
    }
}
```

BaseFragment

```
abstract class BaseFragment:Fragment(),CoroutineScope {
private lateinit var job:Job

override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = job + Dispatchers.Main

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    job = Job()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    job.cancel()
}
```

ShowAdapter

```
class ShowAdapter(private val customerList:ArrayList<Customer>,private val onItemClickListener: onItemClickListener):RecyclerView.Adapter<ShowAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ShowAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.note_row,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ShowAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.emName.text = customerList[position].name
        holder.itemView.emPosition.text = customerList[position].position
        holder.itemView.emAddress.text = customerList[position].address
        holder.itemView.emPhone.text = customerList[position].phone


        holder.itemView.emUpdate.setOnClickListener {
            val action = ShowFragmentDirections.actionAddNote()
            action.customer = customerList[position]
            Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(action)
        }

        holder.itemView.emDelete.setOnClickListener {
            onItemClickListener.onClick(customerList[position],position)
        }

    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return customerList.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
}
```

[image: Error]

How can i solve this, please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ShowFragment`, you are invoking `noteDelete` by passing a wrong null object.

so try the following

```
override fun onClick(item: Customer, position: Int) {
    launch {
                context?.let {
                    CustomerDatabase(it).getNoteDao().noteDelete(item)
                    val c = CustomerDatabase(it).getNoteDao().getAllNote()
                    (recyclerView.adapter as ShowAdapter).addNewList(c)
                }
    }
```

```
//add this function in your adapter

 fun addnewList(newCustomerList:ArrayList<Customer>){
     customerList = newCustomewList
     notifyDataSetChanged()
 }
```

Comment: there no error but still the item is not deleting ,can you please help me?Thank you @rcs

Comment: @user10997009 did you try passing `item` instead of `customerNote!!` in your `onClick`, coz `customerNote` is null and that's causing the app to crash. Try pasting my answer and see if it works

Comment: I can't understand,can you please explain?Thank you

Comment: you are referencing the wrong object in your delete logic, try pasting the code I updated in your `ShowFragment` and see if it works

Comment: yes,i am passing item but it's not working

Comment: It is indeed working, the item is been deleted but not visually seen because you need to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` to observe the changes

Comment: launch {
            context?.let {
                CustomerDatabase(it).getNoteDao().noteDelete(item)
                recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                it.toast("Deleted!")

            }

Comment: I am using notifyDatasetChanged() but still it's not woring

Comment: @user10997009 check the edited answer now and see if it works

Comment: your previous answer is correct but it's not delete item instants,when i jump another fragment and back to this fragment then it's delete

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227449/discussion-between-rcs-and-user10997009).